# Strange error in simple javacv

Tags: java, javacv

I get very strange error with javacv 0.9 when opening an image. The code I have written so far is:

```
IplImage image = cvLoadImage("/path/to/image.png");
final CanvasFrame canvas = new CanvasFrame("test");      
canvas.showImage(image);
canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

The `image.png` should pop up after pressing the button (jgoodies in IDEA 13.1), but instead i get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (0) and height (0) cannot be <= 0
```

IDE indicates that the error source is this line:

```
final CanvasFrame canvas = new CanvasFrame("test");
```

Could somebody help me?

Comment: Are you sure the intended file is existing in given path. You can check it using `System.out.println(new File("/path/to/image.png").exist());`

Comment: yes i'm sure. the file exists

Comment: but it's working now. ide restart solved the problem...